# Facebook iOS SDK: FBSDKMessageDialog switching back to App

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an App which uses the FBSDKMessageDialog from the actual Facebook iOS SDK to communicate with friends.

Actually i have the problem that the Facebook Messenger is directly switching back to my App (80% of all tries - sometimes it works). Without any user interaction. Normally it should switch back to my App after sending the Message.

That's what i am doing:

```
if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb-messenger://")!)) {
    let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentDescription = description;
    content.contentTitle = title
    content.contentURL = NSURL(string: url)
    content.imageURL = NSURL(string: self.appIconUrl)
    FBSDKMessageDialog.showWithContent(content, delegate: self)
}
```

**Update

Found a new hint with `func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)`

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=103 "(null)" UserInfo={error_message=Error parsing link, error_code=103, app_id=870185466371832}
```

I will check that.

**Update #2

After unwrapping the URL it still doesn't work. The URL looks good but the same error. If i define google.com as URL it seems to work all the time...very strange.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: Hard to tell... i really do not exactly know what i have done to get it working. As in the App (URL) everything was finde i've checked the websitei was linking to. Checked with Facebook URL Linter, optimizied meta tags, checked the websserver logfiles for any infos when Facebook came for crawling. Now it's definetily working... May these hints help you!